# Restore inapp purchase Ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I having problem to get the previus purchases from app store. I can buy products and validate the receipt but when I try to restore them, the list of purchased transactions is empty. :(
Any idea? Something i forgoten or dosen't it work in sandbox?

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray*)transactions
{
  //Is only fired when buying and not restoring.
     for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
};
}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");
[self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
_isPurchased = YES;
[self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Comment: Please show you "completeTransaction" method

Comment: You can try implementing `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` method to get all completed transactions in `queue.transactions`.

Comment: Done that, but there is no transactions. The only thing I need is to get the latest transactions, should not be so hard to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## define kMDPulseSubscriptionProductIdentifier @"Your Product ID here...."

SKPaymentTransactionOBserver:

```
   - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
   {
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"Prossing.............");
            
            break;
            
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        {
            
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt
                                  
                                  options:kNilOptions 
                                  error:&error];
            NSLog(@"JSON Receipt: %@",jsonDict);
            
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:jsonDict forKey:@"A"];
            NSLog(@"Purchase was a Success.....");
        }
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            
            NSLog(@"Purchase cancelled");
            
            
            break;
            
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            
            default:
            
            break;
    }         
}
}


  - (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
   }

 - (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
   NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

   [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
  }

  - (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

  NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];


 if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
 {
    NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
   
 }

  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
 }

  - (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:kMDPulseSubscriptionProductIdentifier]) {
    [self purchaseSubscriptionWithMonths:1];
}

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]       postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

   }
   - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%s","User Cancel.");



 }

  - (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
  NSLog(@"Restore completed transactions finished.");
  NSLog(@" Number of transactions in queue: %d", [[queue transactions] count]);
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *trans in [queue transactions])
  {
    NSLog(@" transaction id %@ for product %@.", [trans transactionIdentifier], [[trans payment] productIdentifier]);
    NSLog(@" original transaction id: %@ for product %@.", [[trans originalTransaction] transactionIdentifier],
          [[[trans originalTransaction] payment]productIdentifier]);
    
    
    if ([[[trans payment] productIdentifier] isEqual: kMDPulseSubscriptionProductIdentifier]) {
        
        NSLog(@"Purchase Restored");
        
        // Do your stuff to unlock
      }
    }
   }


 - (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
 {
    NSLog(@"Restore Tapped in transaction process");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method for restoring

-(void)restoreCompletedTransactions

{

```
NSLog(@"Restore Tapped in transaction process");
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

}

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue

{

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"IN APP PURCHASE" message:@"Processing" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[alert addSubview:progress];
[progress startAnimating];
[alert show];

[progress release];

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
{
 // Use this Commented code to Log and check details about your Products

/**    
    NSLog(@"%d",queue.transactions.count);
    NSMutableArray * purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];

        NSLog(@"%@",purchasedItemIDs);


    }*/

if( queue.transactions.count == 0 ) {
    
    // User hav't purchased yet.
    NSLog(@"User hav't purchased yet.");
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restore" message:@"You have not purchased yet"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    
}else {
    
    // Upgrade to Full version.
    NSLog(@"Upgrade to Full version.");
    
    // Do stuffs here

    //finally finish transaction
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    

     }
    
}
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

}

Hope this helps!!